# static inner class and non static outer method

Tags: android

I have a Problem with an ColorPickerDialog http://www.yougli.net/android/a-photoshop-like-color-picker-for-your-android-application/

This ColorPickerDialog has an inner static class...
in this inner static class i need to use "close()" or "dismiss()" on the ColorPickerDialog to close it...

My problem is 
`public class ColorPickerDialog extends Dialog`

The close() and dismiss() methods are non static in Dialog. How can i use this Methods in the inner static class `private static class ColorPickerView extends View` ?

edit...
Here are the important sections from the Code..

```
public class ColorPickerDialog extends Dialog {

public interface OnColorChangedListener {
    void colorChanged(String key, int color);
}

private static class ColorPickerView extends View {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (x > 266 && x < 394 && y > 316 && y < 356){
            savedDialog();
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void savedDialog() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
        .setTitle("Save to profile?")
        .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int which) {
                    }
                })
        .setNegativeButton("No",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int which) {
                    }
                }).show();

    }
}

public ColorPickerDialog(Context context, OnColorChangedListener listener,
        String key, int initialColor, int defaultColor) {
    super(context);

    mListener = listener;
    mKey = key;
    mInitialColor = initialColor;
    mDefaultColor = defaultColor;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    OnColorChangedListener l = new OnColorChangedListener() {
        public void colorChanged(String key, int color) {
            mListener.colorChanged(mKey, color);
            dismiss();
        }
    };

    setContentView(new ColorPickerView(getContext(), l, mInitialColor,
            mDefaultColor));
    setTitle(R.string.pick_a_color);

}
}
```

and here i intatiate the ColorPickerDialog...

```
public class LampsFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            OnColorChangedListener listener = new OnColorChangedListener() {

                @Override
                public void colorChanged(String key, int color) {


                }
            };
            ColorPickerDialog cp = new ColorPickerDialog(getActivity(), listener, key, arg2, arg2);
            cp.show();
            return false;
        }
    });

    lv.setAdapter(files);

    return view;
}

}
```

I want to close the ColorPickerDialog after pressing "YES" on the AlertDialog from the the inner static class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, unless you can get an instance of the `ColorPickerDialog` somehow. Is the `static` modifier on the inner class is strictly required? static inner classes do not have access to the instances of the surrounding class. You can either make `ColorPickerView` a member class (non-static inner class), or pass a reference to the surrounding class to it (either in constructor or via a setter method call).

Member classes have an implicit reference to the surrounding instance, and you can make call the methods of the surrounding classes directly. If there is name-hiding; for ex. suppose the `ColorPickerView` also declares a `close()` method, you can call the outer-class method with `ColorPickerDialog.this.close()`.

Comment: Jeah the inner class dont need to be static for my project this time - i will edit it now to "private class ColorPickerView..."

ColorPickerDialog.this.close() was my idea, too. But it don´t work with the static modifier.

Thank You